# Are you playing Diablo 3? Why don't you play with us?

Tags: discussion, diablo-3, community

Blah blah blah enormously hyped, blah blah persistant multiplayer yadda yadda battletag and built in chat client, I'm not going to bother boring you with things you already know.

Instead, I'm just gonna put it out there:

If you're going to be playing Diablo 3, and would like to play or chat with **Super Awesome Gaming.SE Regulars** like the amazing Sterno, or the inimitable StrixVaria, or that LessPopMoreFizz jackass, a bunch of us are adding our BattleTags and other relevant information to [This Easy To Use Internet Spreadsheet List Thing.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvR2Eb3lVDhIdGRER3FrWTdaR1J3LTRYbGVESjlqTGc)

You should add yours. And then we can play Diablo 3 together. And I can try to sell you lots of [SoJ's](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/stone-of-jordan) at above market prices. Because that's what Internet Friends Are For.

[image: Preferred classes]
[image: Regions]

Comment: Isn't it global? Why region? (I don't remember selecting one in the beta)

Comment: @JuanManuel It's not global. There is a default region depending on which version of the game you selected, but it's possible to choose to play on a different region if you want.

Comment: @JuanManuel there are three regions, Americas, Asia, and EU - the game chooses a default based on your location of purchase. While you can freely jump between regions to engage in multiplayer, your characters, items, and even your name will stay behind. Your identity in each region is totally separate and you cannot transfer anything between them.

Comment: Great, thanks. I updated my record.

Comment: "That LessPopMoreFizz jackass" has a nice ring to it, I think.

Comment: I added a background color to my row just because @RavenDreamer has it and I didn't want to be less

Comment: I'm in :)  A little late but still day 1 :)

Comment: That spreadsheet needs a 'last updated' column, I doubt any of you are still in Normal

Comment: @Alok The difficulty column really doesn't make a whole lot of sense. Might as well put "Level".

Comment: @Resorath Level would be far better agreed.

Comment: The spreadsheet is public guys, go ahead and edit it.

Comment: Something change with this? I specifically remember a lot more names last time I checked. Also, everyone currently on the list is in the European region, and I really don't think that everyone who's put there name in the sheet is from Europe. Was really looking forward to adding some of you guys.

Answer (score 2):

It seems gaming.se/arqade is big enough to attract trolls even to its online spreadsheets :( Any chance of also having a curated read-only version?

Posting an answer because, might as well mention a couple of other things while I'm at it:

- Not going to sign up, since my SE signup isn't a random nick and I keep it separate from online mmo identities
- Would also be too scared to play with some of you tbh, I can just see side quests being aborted for being 'too specific' and TPing to town to sell blue stuff would be 'not constructive' ;)

I mainly check the list to see if I group with one of you in some random public game (not happened so far, but considering my limited hours and the D3 pop its not a surprise)