# Arqade clans in games?

Tags: discussion, community

After reading [this post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4649/are-you-playing-diablo-3-why-dont-you-play-with-us), I thought about possibly creating a Diablo 3 community where people from Arqade could play together.

Are there any other games that already feature such clans / communities?

Comment: Diablo 3 already has one :)

Comment: @StrixVaria What's the name of it?

Comment: There are such communities, I created the Diablo III one on EU myself. It doesn't have many members though as most of the very active Arqade users that might know about it play on the US server.

Comment: @MadScientist what is it called and can i join in? and how?

Comment: @MadScientist Same question as Alex

Comment: I'd like to create one for US, does anyone know if there is one currently?

Comment: @WizLiz It's called simply "Arqade", should be easy to find.

Comment: @WizLiz I found this [REAPER OF SOULS™ FIRST LOOK: CLANS AND COMMUNITIES](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/12891941/reaper-of-souls%E2%84%A2-first-look-clans-and-communities-2-19-2014) I haven't tried it myself but it seems theres a way that you can search for clans

Answer (score 1):

I have a Minecraft server than I'm happy to let people on (must speak English though so we can communicate). It's a 1.8 snapshot server. Details given out at my discretion at the moment. Send me a chat if you want them.

It's not a clan but I often play Payday 2 with 2 other friends (leaving one spot open), so if anyone else plays that you're welcome to join in too when we need a 4th

Comment: More info about the Minecraft server? Since the last one went away I've been playing single player, which isn't the same.

Comment: What sort of info do you want to know about it?

Comment: The host name or IP and port for starters would be good.  How are we supposed to play with you if we don't know how to connect?

Comment: Oops, I forget to mention that I'm not making the public as such yet, I'm giving them out at my discretion at the moment through chat. I can send them you now if you like MBraedley/shanodin